# GML file data extraction

Tags: qgis, gml, citygml

I'm completely new with QGIS and GML files. I managed to open one of GML file that can be downloaded here: https://geodaten.bayern.de/opengeodata/OpenDataDetail.html?pn=lod2
These files are LoD2 data, which means that the geometry of the buildings is described with detail.

The problem is that when I go to the attributes table, I can't extract the data for the roofs, like inclination, orientation and type of roof. How can this be done?

Comment: Are the attributes definitely in the GML? You can open in a text editor to check